# How to display html page correctly for all resolution monitors and for mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css, screen-resolution

I'm new in html, css

I trying to create simple "Coming soon" page using html/css.

It looks good on my screen but when I tried to see the page via mobile it wasn't.

I have created background image in PS with texts and from code I'm adding to images (facebook, Linkedin) linked to fb and in.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>MySite</title>
<style>

html { 
  background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;

    position: fixed;
    top: 85%;
    left: 58%;
    font-size: 48px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}
div1 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;

    position: fixed;
    top: 85%;
    left: 65%;
    font-size: 48px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div>

        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/myPage" target="_blank"> 
        <img src="f.png" width="60px" height="60px"
          name="f_name" onmouseover="f_name.style.width='58px';     f_name.style.height='58px';"
        onmouseout="f_name.style.width='60px'; f_name.style.height='60px';"/> 
       </a> 

    </div>

    <div1>

        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/myPage" target="_blank"> <img src="in.png" width="60px" height="60px"
        name="in_name" onmouseover="in_name.style.width='58px'; in_name.style.height='58px';"
        onmouseout="in_name.style.width='60px'; in_name.style.height='60px';"/> 
        </a>

    </div1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try media queries.. for different resolution

Comment: Try bootstrap css container/row/column component

Comment: I don't know how to do them, I'm totaly new in web programming.
can you give me some codes or link where can I find them?

Comment: Don't use `<div1></div1>` unless you are meaning to use custom elements. If you need to uniquely identify elements use the id attribute: `<div id="div1"></div>` and use css id selector `#div1` in your css

Comment: read this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: @ayety, you won't get a tutorial on media queries here, though knowing how people jump on new HTML/CSS/JS questions someone may write you a simple example just for the rep... Try [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries) nice beginners guide and come back with a more detailed question if you are still struggling

Comment: Mostly dont give the values in pixels, If you are looking for responsive. give the values in %

Comment: what means this attributes value? onmouseover="in_name.style.width='58px'; in_name.style.height='58px';"
        onmouseout="in_name.style.width='60px'; in_name.style.height='60px';"

Comment: @punithasubramaniv it just makes images to resize on mouse touch

Answer (score 1):

You can use media query for responsive like following:

```
/* MEDIA QUERY FOR IPAD LANDSCAPTE */
@media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1100px) {
}

/* MEDIA QUERY FOR IPAD PORTRAIT */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
}

/* MEDIA QUERY FOR ALL MOBILE DEVICES : HAVING LESS THAN 767 RESOLUTION */
@media (max-width: 767px) {    
}

/* MEDIA QUERY FOR EXTRA SMALL : IPHONE LANDSCAPE & PORTRAIT DEVICES */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
}
```

Here, You can find good tutorial if you are a beginner with the responsive sites.

[Reference 1:](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

[Reference 2:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 1):

There are frameworks out there that will do a lot of this for you and if you're starting I recommend that you familiarise yourself with one. One of the most popular is [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com).

### Getting Started

One of the key concepts within bootstrap for responsive layout is that of the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). I won't go through all the possible options you have with the grid system but the general gist is this.

There are four main "screen sizes":

- Extra-small `xs` ( < 768px wide)
- Small `sm` ( >= 768px wide )
- Medium `md` ( >= 992px wide )
- Large `lg` ( >= 1200px wide )

As you may have noticed smaller screen sizes are given priority. In other words, if I define an `xs` rule it becomes the default and to do something different on a `md` screen I need to explicitly do so.

### The Grid

There are 12 columns by default. I can add classes to my html elements which tell bootstrap how I want them to behave when the screen width changes.

```
<!-- The full container width (i.e. 12/12) on extra-small screens and above
     and half the container width (i.e. 6/12) from medium width and above -->
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"></div>
```

This example shows how you can specify the behaviour of a div (or any paragraph-like element) for certain screen-size thresholds. The div in the example will be the full width of the container for `xs` and `sm` screen widths but half the width of the container on `md` and `lg` screen widths.

### jsFiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/rlgod/oyzayqn6/1/

Have a play with this JSFiddle to get a better idea of how that works. In particular stretch the 'Result' segment and see what happens to the contents at certain thresholds.

### Further Reading

1. http://getbootstrap.com/css/
2. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed-complete

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to make your sire responsive, Make sure you mentioned Viewport i your header.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

If you mention the above one and using media query, Ur site will become responsive.

Comment: @AwalGarg - Thanks!! Can you please give specific reason for your comment.